SQL to find parents where ALL children are different
I have a table package_scans with fields package_id and scan_id, and another table scan_content with scan_id and epc.
There is a 1-N relation between the tables, so for each package_scan there are multiple entries in scan_content.
I am trying to find all package scans, where there exists another scan but with all different content.
Example (for sake of simplicity all scans have exactly 2 epc, could be anywhere from 1-*):
Table package_scans:



package_id
scan_id




1
111


1
112


2
221


2
222


3
331


4
441


4
442


4
443



Table scan_content:



scan_id
epc




111
a1


111
a2


112
a3


112
a4


221
b1


221
b2


222
b2


222
b3


331
c1


331
c2


441
d1


441
d2


442
d1


442
d2


443
d3


443
d4



The only valid result would be package_id 1, as this package has two scans (111 and 112) with completely different epc.
Package 2 is not relevant to me, it also has two scans (221 and 222) but there is an overlap in the epc (both have b2).
Package 3 not relevant to me as it only has a single scan.
Package 4 does have an overlap between scan 441 and 442, but scan 443 is all new and therefore package 4 is relevant and needs to be part of the result set.
I tried with different versions of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS, but I only get to the point where I get both package_id 1 and 2 as a result, not only 1.
Here is my best approach:
SELECT package_id FROM package_scans ps1 
JOIN scan_content sc1 ON ps1.scan_id = sc1.scan_id
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM package_scans ps2
      WHERE ps1.package_id = ps2.package_id
      AND ps1.scan_id != ps2.scan_id
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM scan_content sc2
            WHERE ps2.scan_id = sc2.scan_id
            AND sc1.epc = sc2.epc
            )
      )

Here is my thoughts behind the my SQL:
There is a package_scan, where there exists another package_scan for the same package_id but a different scan_id. This second scan does not have a single epc that matches the epcs from the first scan.
Sadly this SQL results in both package_id 1 and 2.
Thanks in advance for any tips!

Are you familar with the concept of relational division? There are examples in SQL available.

Which DBMS is this?

The epc cannot repeat per package, is that all?

Concerning your questions:

No I am not familiar with relational division so far
This is on PostgreSQL
correct, epc is unique per package


OK so just to clarify the new requirements: if there is a package_id which has at least one scan_id with all its epc not overlapping any other scan_id set of epc then you want that package_id included? What happens if it overlaps a set from a different package_id entirely? Eg what if you had an extra row 443  |   a1 ?

Yes only the first case is relevant to me, if there is an overlap in scanned epcs over different package_ids (as in your example 443  |   a1) this is a different usecase and should not be part of this SQL

So if that row existed what would the result be?

package_id 4 would still be in the result set, as I only want to compare epcs over the same package_id.

UPDATED ANSWER:
The overlapings are problem that require double joins to get the result..
WITH    /*  S a m p l e    D a t a  */
  package_scans ( package_id, scan_id ) AS 
    ( Select 1, 111 Union All 
      Select 1, 112 Union All 
      Select 2, 221 Union All 
      Select 2, 222 Union All 
    Select 2, 223 Union All      /* added row  */
      Select 3, 331 
    ),
  scan_content ( scan_id, epc ) AS 
    ( Select 111, 'a1' Union All 
      Select 111, 'a2' Union All 
      Select 112, 'a3' Union All 
      Select 112, 'a4' Union All 
      Select 221, 'b1' Union All
      Select 221, 'b2' Union All 
      Select 222, 'b2' Union All
      Select 222, 'b3' Union All 
  Select 223, 'b4' Union All      /* added row  */
  Select 223, 'b5' Union All      /* added row  */
      Select 331, 'c1' Union All
      Select 331, 'c2' 
    ), 

... create cte for multiple joins in main sql ...
  pcte AS
    ( Select     ps.package_id,  ps.scan_id, s.epc, 
                    Count(ps.package_id) Over(Partition By ps.package_id) /
                    Count(ps.package_id) Over(Partition By ps.scan_id) as ps_count, 
                    Count(s.epc) Over(Partition By ps.package_id, s.epc) as s_count
        From       package_scans ps
        Inner Join scan_content s ON( s.scan_id = ps.scan_id )
      )

... you need to self join the cte with the aggregation TWICE: once for epc and once for scan_id uniqueness ...
/*    M a i n    S Q L :    */
SELECT p.package_id 
FROM   pcte p
INNER JOIN (Select package_id, epc, Max(s_count) as max_count
            From pcte 
            Where ps_count > 1
            Group By package_id, epc
            Having Max(s_count) = 1 ) s ON(s.package_id = p.package_id And 
                                          s.epc = p.epc)
INNER JOIN (Select package_id, scan_id, Max(s_count) as max_count
            From pcte 
            Where ps_count > 1
            Group By package_id, scan_id
            Having Max(s_count) = 1 ) s2 ON(s2.package_id = p.package_id And 
                                            s2.scan_id = p.scan_id)
WHERE     p.ps_count > 1 
GROUP BY  p.package_id

/*  R e s u l t : 
package_id 
----------
         1    
         2    */

See the fiddle here.

Hi! Sadly this approach does not work in all cases, imagine having an additional scan for package_id 2, scan_id 223 with all new epcs (b4, b5). As this scan is all new epcs compared to scan 221 and 222 I would need package_id 2 to be part of the result set.

@Budenzauber Just posted an update, please check it again....

@Budenzauber Sorry - still not ok... Working on it ...

@Budenzauber Now it should do the job, please check it and let me know ...

works like a charm, thanks!

This is a type of Relational Division Without Remainder, with the twist that you have multiple divisors, and that you need the dividend to be above 1.
There are a number of solutions. Many would end up self-joining multiple times, or use window functions, but I don't think it's necessary here. In this case, I think an efficient method might be as follows:
Group by package_id and epc, taking the count per epc, as well as the min and max scan_id.
Then group again just by package_id, checking that we the min and max scan_id are different (and therefore at least two scans), and that the count for every epc is 1 (and therefore there are no overlaps anywhere in the package_id.
SELECT
  ps.package_id
FROM (
    SELECT
      ps.package_id,
      COUNT(*) AS count_per_epc,
      MIN(sc.scan_id) AS min_scan,
      MAX(sc.scan_id) AS max_scan
    FROM package_scans ps
    JOIN scan_content sc ON sc.scan_id = ps.scan_id
    GROUP BY
      ps.package_id,
      sc.epc
) ps
GROUP BY
  ps.package_id
HAVING MIN(ps.min_scan) <> MAX(ps.max_scan)  -- at least two scans
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ps.count_per_epc > 1 THEN 1 END) = 0  -- none;

An alternative more concise but more obscure syntax for the final condition is:
   AND COUNT(NULLIF(ps.count_per_epc, 1)) = 0;

db<>fiddle

The scan_id from my example is a bit simplified, as in reality this field is a UUID, does your approach with MIN/MAX still work?

Edit: Actually the data type is "text" and based on the Postgres documentation that should still work. Will try and let you know!

Same problem as with the first suggested solution, if there is an overlap between 2 scans for a package (as in 221 and 222), but there is a third scan (223) with all new epcs then package_id 2 should be in the result set, but as there is an overlap with at least one epc (b2) this does not work.
I have added example scans for package 4 with this scenario in my question above.
